# cannot push the ios for juniper ex3300

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

I am trying to push the JUNOS image for a Juniper EX3300 from a TFTP server.  First I set IP address, netmask and server IP, then I started the install.  But it shows cannot open package(error 60) came while pushing JUNOS.  Can you suggest some tips?

Comment: Hello! Can you provide CLI output of error message and also confirm that you properly completed all steps, as stated in manual ([link](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB11752&actp=METADATA))